# Sending packets captured with Wireshark on Windows

Tags: windows, server, ip, wireshark, packets

I captured some packets from server(like: ip.addr ==  111.11.11.111 && data), and want to send them again. How to do it? Googling didn't yield any easy way not involving some complex stuff resulting in a script being able to send only this specific request, without any flexibility.

I'am using only Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

A very simple program that can do this is [PlayCap](http://www.signal11.us/oss/playcap/) from [Signal 11 Software](http://www.signal11.us/), but there are several others too.  You might want to have a look at the various [Traffic Generators](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools#Traffic_generators) listed on the Wireshark Tools wiki page for other potential solutions.